# How to add a watermark on a Rechart component (React)?

Tags: reactjs, watermark, recharts

I have built a component using Recharts to show a LineChart. Is there a way to insert a watermark into a Rechart component / React component?

The following is the code for my Rechart component:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { LineChart } from 'recharts';

class MyBarChart extends PureComponent  {
    static jsfiddleUrl = 'https://jsfiddle.net/alidingling/xqjtetw0/';

    render() {
        const data = this.props.counts;

        return (
            <div>
            <LineChart
                width={500}
                height={300}
                data={data}
                margin={{
                    top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5,
                }}
            >
            <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
            <XAxis dataKey="time" />
            <YAxis />
            <Tooltip />
            <Legend />
            <Line type="monotone" dataKey="Negative" stroke="#cc0a00" activeDot={{ r: 8 }} />
            <Line type="monotone" dataKey="Neutral" stroke="#9e9e9e" />
            <Line type="monotone" dataKey="Positive" stroke="#00d14d" />
            </LineChart>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default MyBarChart;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I've just had this come up. I went with a solution of using the :after property of the div around the graph and some CSS positioning.

I added a Responsive container (not strictly needed, but enables scaling with various resolutions) around your chart:

```
<ResponsiveContainer className="watermark" width="100%" height={300} >
    <LineChart data={data} margin={{top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5}}>
        <XAxis dataKey="name"/>
        <YAxis/>
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
        <Tooltip/>
        <Legend />
        <Line type="monotone" dataKey="pv" stroke="#8884d8" activeDot={{r: 8}}/>
        <Line type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#82ca9d" />
    </LineChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
```

I then added the following CSS updates:

```
.watermark {
  position: relative;
}

.watermark:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 210px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 30px;      
  background-image: url('https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-256-thumb/cat-131-378998.png');
  background-size: auto;
  background-position: 30px 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.1;
}
```

Here's the result: 
[image]

You can see it in the below JSfiddle (for some reason it bugs out sometimes): 
[Updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hz79a6bv/1/)